# PHP script to play file saved in local network PC

Tags: javascript, php

i want to know if it is possible to play audio file save in some PC in local network of PHP server.
Through PHP I can read file name .
Now I want to pass that name and location path to wavesurfer.js.

When I put file in same location of PHP script I can play through JavaScript code I want to know how to play file which is located in local network.

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">
<head>
 

    <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
      <meta name="Author" content="">
  

        <meta name="Keywords" content="">
      <meta name="Description" content="">
     <title>Document</title>


         <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>


  
   </head>
    <body>
 
        <?php
        $path = '\\\\192.168.1.xx\musicfiles'; 

        $user = "Administrator";
        $pass = "xxxxxx;
        $drive_letter = "Z";

        system("net use ".$drive_letter.": \"".$path."\" ".$pass." /user:".$user." /persistent:no>nul 2>&1");
        $location = $drive_letter.":/2412";
        $audio = [];
        if ($handle = opendir($location)) {
                while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) 
               {
                    $audio[]=$entry;
                //echo "I am in";
                //echo "$entry";
                //echo "</br>";
             
            } 
            //print_r($audio);
         $file = $audio[3];
        
        
        closedir($handle);
    
    }

    ?>
          <div id="waveform" style="position:relative"></div>
          <div class="controls" style="text-align:center;">
                                <button class="playin" onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()">            
                                Play
                                /
                                Pause
                                </button>                   
                            </div>
         </body>

     <script type="text/javascript">
    console.clear();
    var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create
        ({
        container: '#waveform',
        waveColor: 'violet',
        progressColor: 'purple'
     
        });
        var file = '<?php echo "$file" ?>';
        console.log(file);
        wavesurfer.load();// **here what should be the syntax**
        wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
        wavesurfer.backend.ac.resume();
        wavesurfer.play();
        });    

     </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Fix the format of your question to have the code appear clearly.

Comment: Please check again , and let me know if still you cannot see it clearly.

Comment: The path you pass to wavesurfer needs to be a valid URL which can be accessed via HTTP. A UNC path doesn't count as that. You'd have to map that folder as a virtual directory in your webserver and then pass the path of the virtual directory (plus the filename) to wavesurfer

Comment: @ADyson : do you mean i have map that folder as virtual directory in PHP server .  I have mapped that folder in PHP server with name Y , now I should make URL path to that directory , could you please point me to some reference site , I tried to search , but cannot find anything related to that .

Comment: Well what webserver are you using? IIS? Apache?

Comment: @ADyson Apache2.4

Comment: Is the Apache server running on windows or Linux?

Comment: @ADyson running on windows.

Comment: https://kromey.us/2009/09/apache-on-windows-serving-files-from-the-network-150.html for example. You can search for other similar stuff and related background reading